# Replacing an element within a vector in a list

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors that looks like

```
[[1]][1] 1 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 1 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 2 1 1

[[4]]
[1] 2 2 2
```

I would like the replace the first component of each of the vectors with a `9`. I have tried

```
out <- append(vecs2T2[[1]], y, after=0)
```

but this just adds an `9` in at the start and does not replace it (see below).

```
[1] 9 1 1 2
```

I would like this entry to read `912`.

Answer (score 1):

```
lapply(ll, replace, 1, 9)
```

This goes vector by vector, and `replace`s the 1st item with 9. (Replace's arguments are: (data, list-of-indexes, list-of-values), with the list of values recycled to be as long as the list of indexes.)

`replace()` is just defined as:

```
replace <- function (x, list, values) {
  x[list] <- values
  x
}
```

so you can also use that method.

```
lapply(ll, function(x) { x[1] <- 9 ; x })
```

You can use either with `purrr::map()`, too:

```
purrr::map(ll, ~{ .x[1] <- 9 ; .x })
purrr::map(ll, replace, 1, 9)
```

Head-to-head (not the best microbenchmark setup in the world tho):

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  purr_repl = purrr::map(ll, replace, 1, 9),
  purr_op = purrr::map(ll, ~{ .x[1] <- 9 ; .x }),
  lapp_repl = lapply(ll, replace, 1, 9),
  lapp_op = lapply(ll, function(x) { x[1] <- 9 ; x }),
  Map = Map(function(x, y)c(x, y[-1]), 9, ll)
)
## Unit: microseconds
##       expr    min      lq      mean  median      uq      max neval
##  purr_repl 27.510 29.7555  49.98242 31.4735 33.4805 1506.400   100
##    purr_op 84.415 86.9550 125.07364 90.0665 98.9465 2423.406   100
##  lapp_repl  4.422  4.8350   5.94472  5.1965  5.5930   34.947   100
##    lapp_op  4.672  5.4250  19.14590  5.9045  6.5015 1215.477   100
##        Map 10.670 12.2490  28.94712 13.5935 14.7170 1238.311   100
```

Comment: @hrbrmstr - thanks for all the edits, but the bottom line from your comparison at the bottom is that my original solution is the fastest one, by a lot, isn't it?

Comment: Yep, hence why I added it. Your solution was  (some folks have their heads stuck in the tidyverse so they'll appreciate the purrr additions despite the serious performance hit). Adding the alternates outside your answer seemed wrong since it's all the same thing (just less performant)

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to use `Map` and concatenate `9` with the each vector minus its first element

```
Map(function(x, y)c(x, y[-1]), 9, l1)
```